# How to get a component to be fixed at the bottom until the user scrolls to the footer with CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and CSS in JS with Emotion.  When on mobile, I need a button to be fixed at the bottom of the viewport until the user scrolls to the footer.  At that point, it needs to be fixed at the top of the footer.

The button is a reusable component that can be dropped in where it's needed and be shown/hidden with media queries.

I have tried

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

☝️ That works great until the footer is in view.  I need it to stick to the top of the footer.

I have also tried

```
position: sticky;
top: (some amount of px);
```

For some reason, position sticky has no effect in this situation.  I assume it doesn't work in child components (it does work on the header).

If there is a way to get `position: sticky` to work in a child component, please share that with me.  I am open to any other approaches as well.  Additionally, we are using Material UI, if there is a lesser known feature that will work with MUI that is an option too.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit fussy but if the `sticky` elements parents are siblings it can work.

a small POC:

```css
.content {
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: grey;
  height: 1000px;
}

.btn {
  position: sticky;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  top: calc(100vh - 55px);
  z-index: 10;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <div class="btn"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>


  <div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your example works great in isolation, but `position: sticky` does not work in nested React components as far as I can tell.

Comment: it can and I did it once, you need to pay attention but you can do it

Comment: In my case, the parents are not siblings and it's not possible to make them siblings in the structure of this app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [react-use-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-scroll) to get the user scroll position and change your styles in emotion after some scroll value

Comment: True, but it causes a TON of renders that I'm trying to avoid.